# How to do editing and deleting function in auto generated table in php ,mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Actually am new in php, i created one fetching page in php. Where am fetching data from the database and will display on the auto generated table. I added two button also. One for Delete the specific row from database and another one for edit the details from the database. In database email_id column is unique. So both the Delete Edit operation will do by email_id. Can Any one tell me , how i write Ajax function for editing and deleting. Code is given below

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><!--Dquip--></title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Arvo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dropotron-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.slidertron-1.0.js"></script>
<style>
label
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:;
}
table,tr,th,td
{
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
table
{
  width:75%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}
th,td
{
  height: 50px;
}
td
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button
{
    width:75px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color:dodgerblue;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
</style>
<center>
<script>
function deleteABC()
{


}

function editABC()
{

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h4 align="right"><a href="loginpage.php">Logout</a></h4>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">..</a></h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-wrapper">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="calenderindex.html"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
                <li><span>Blog</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="first"> <a href="index">About US</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="search">Function Area</a> </li>
                        <li class="last"> <a href="about">Contact US</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Photos</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
                <li><span>Datas</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="first"> <a href="index.php">Add Details</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="map.php">Map view</a> </li>
                        <li class="last"> <a href="fetchinghome.php">view Details</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#menu').dropotron();
        </script> 
        </div></br>
        <h1><font color="white">Enter the dates to retrieve the data</font></h1></br></br>
<form method="POST" action="fetchinghome.php">
<label>Role ID:</label><input type="text" name="role" placeholder="Enter the starting date"> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Go" class="button">
</form>





<?php
//include "loginpage.php";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "calender";
   $role=$_REQUEST['role'];


   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



   if(! $conn )
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
   if ($role == 'admin')
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration";
}
elseif($role=="M%")
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration where reporting_manager='$role' or role='$role'";
}
else
{


    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration WHERE role='$role'";
}

      // $sql="SELECT * FROM registration where reporting_manager='$role'";

   $retval = mysqli_query( $conn,$sql );

   if(! $retval )
   {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
   }


            $arr;
            $i=0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))
    {
        $arr[$i]=$row;
        $i++;
        /*
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row[0]."</td><td>";
        echo $row[1]."</td><td>";
        echo $row[2]."</td><td>";
        echo $row[3]."</td><td>";
        echo $row[4]."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        */

    }
    $str='';
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $brn='<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteABC('.$arr[$i]['email_id'].')">';
        $brn1='<input type="button" value="Edit" onClick="editABC('.$arr[$i]['email_id'].')">';
            $str=$str . '<tr><td>'. $arr[$i]['name'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['email_id'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['mobile_no'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['address'].'</td><td>'.$arr[$i]['role'].'</td><td>'.$brn.'</td><td>'.$brn1.'</td></tr>';

    }

    echo "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
          <tr>   
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>".$str."</table>";


   }

   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

   mysqli_close($conn);
}   


?>
</body>
</html>

Please help me to write the Ajax function for those.
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteABC(email_id)
{
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete..!"))
   {
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "your url here",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {email_id: email_id},
        success: function (data)
        {

            //your success code if deleted..
        }
    });
  }
}

function editABC(email_id)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "your url here",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {email_id: email_id},
        success: function (data)
        {
            //your success code if edited 

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: inside the success should i write the mysql query?

Comment: for what purpose ?

Comment: can you please tell me, where should i write sql query and how to use. Because  I dont know how to use ajax function in php

Comment: Actually i want to delete and edit entire row. For that no need to write any mysql query?

Comment: you have to write a code in your php page and that php page is called via ajax function by url attribute that i showed on the ajax function

Comment: how can i call this ajax function from that page?

Comment: <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{
  $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "calender";
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   if(! $conn )
   {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
if($_POST['emai_id'])
{
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']);
$delete = "DELETE FROM registration WHERE email_id='$id'";
mysql_query( $delete);
}
}   
   echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
   mysqli_close($conn);
} 
?>

Comment: why are you always make database connection again in page ? just use single database connection page , and call it in your every page

Comment: when you delete the record at the end type echo "success"; and in ajax function success check the data value if success then remove the row using jquery okay

Comment: am really sorry, am not getting the things. Is this possible for you to give the code for deletion. the problem is i never use the ajax function for auto generated table. If you don't mind will u write the code for deletion. I am a self learner... In fetchinghome.php what code i need to write and the php file where writing sql command